# paypal Expresscheckout allow transaction between buyer and seller event if the balance is 0 USD?

Tags: java, paypal, express-checkout

Im using Express checkout to buy a product from site(5 USD)
but the sandbox account allow payment even if the personal account has 0 Balance Im confused

check my account below
-Account One :xxxxxx@gmail.com              -balance : 0 USD           -Type:Personal

Account Two :yyyyyyfacilitator@hotmail.com  -balance:400               -Type :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your sandbox account is not set up to automatically transfer money from bank account if balance is 0.  This was a default setting for me.

Your paypal balance might be 0, but by default paypal is hooking up fake bank account and fake credit card to your sandbox account.  This allows transaction to go through, because even tho you have 0 balance it pulls the funds out of the fake bank or fake credit card.

Comment: Mr mike 
could you please provide exact steps please cause im new on this there are alot of settings for Person , Business accounts and for application

Comment: well, it depends what you want to do exactly.

Comment: i preview some products on my website when the user checkout i produce a token then i redirect the user to paypal page, the user logged in using his personal sandbox account with 0 USD credit,after the user pay my product he will automatically retrieved to my site and the json response confirm that process is completed without indicator that user doesn't has sufficient money on his account 'jsone response' status is completed

Comment: Well like I said the user has 0USD paypal balance, but the sandbox account is set up with the fake bank information and fake credit card.  In case there is 0 balance on the users account and user makes a purchase, the money is transfered from his fake bank or fake credit card. Look here for example http://community.ebay.com/t5/Archive-PayPal/If-my-Paypal-balance-is-0-but-I-have-my-debit-card-chained-to-my/qaq-p/9989047

Comment: is this accepted when i lunching my app to live the user who have 0 balance can charge and the response that i get from paypal API is completed without indication that user balance isn't enough
cause i need to update user balance locally on my db depend on the response from paypal API.

Comment: It will give you an error if the user can not pay you.  Sandbox by default is set up so the user can ALWAYS pay you.  This is only on sandbox default setup tho.